# Hodge * Operation on a non-coordinate basis

Tags: differential-geometry, hodge-theory

I was reading Nakahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics, where I saw a claim that for a non-coordinate basis $\{\theta^\alpha\}=\{e^{\alpha}_{\ \ \mu}dx^\mu\}$, the Hodge * operation becomes
$$*(\theta^{\alpha_1}\land\cdots\land\theta^{\alpha_r})=\frac{1}{(m-r)!}\varepsilon^{\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_r}_{\qquad\ \ \beta_{r+1}\cdots\beta_m}\theta^{\beta_{r+1}}\land\cdots\land\theta^{\beta_m}.$$
Does anyone know why this is the case? This is on page 290. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is mentioned in the wikipedia. Also, I missed some information that the metric is defined by $g_{\mu\nu}=e^{\alpha}_{\ \ \mu}e^{\beta}_{\ \ \nu}\delta_{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: Looks like the $\theta*\alpha$ are assumed to be an orthonormal coframe. I do not have the book, so you’ll need to read carefully.